# Locking an OData DataServiceContext when calling from multiple BackgroundWorkers

Tags: silverlight, backgroundworker, odata

I have a Silverlight 4 application that connects to an OData service. My model is submitting multiple queries to the service in parallel and in the query callback I am processing the results using a backgroundworker.

This works great if I am making one call, but as soon as I make more than one call in parallel - sometimes it works -  but most of the time I get an exception in the dataservice context when I call EndExecute (it appears to be when it is adding entities to its internal change tracking mechanism.)

So I decided to lock the data service at the point I call EndExecute

```
lock (dataService)
{
    results = query.EndExecute(queryCallback).ToList<Video>(); 
}
```

Which fixed the problem and it now reliably processes the data requests.

My question twofold - is this a recomended practice? Is the OData context not thread safe?

Comment: Are you using a single 'query' instance of the OData service, or does each threaded request have its own service instance?

Comment: I am using one instance of the odata service - I considered creating an instance per query but was not sure if that was recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataServiceContext is not thread-safe. It doesn't have any thread affinity, but it doesn't support having more than one thread calling into it concurrently.

So yes, you have to ensure that only one thread enters the context and associated objects (e.g. query objects) at a time by using a lock or some other means.

Comment: Could I create multiple instances of the odata service as an alternative to locking a single instance? Pros/cons?